# botão para retorno ao topo da página com animação da página subindo com JavaScript

Tags: javascript

É possível fazer uma animação de scroll da tela para voltar ao topo? queria fazer um botão que só aparece ao final da página e sumisse ao clicar, tendo uma animação de scroll subindo até o topo.

Comment: Crie um link como `<a href="#">topo</a>` (customize como desejar, desde que o href= seja o #), então adicione no CSS `html, body { scroll-behavior: smooth; }`. Se desejar pode fazer via JavaScript, aplicando o scrollOptions nos métodos Window.scroll, Window.scrollTo, Window.scrollBy, documentação: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scroll